# How do I disable CSS properties in previous style sheets during RTL conversion?

Tags: css

I am trying to convert my bootstrap theme to a RTL layout. I load two stylesheets due to the orders you see below:

```css
 @import "mycss.css";
 @import "RTL.css";
```

How I can disable any CSS property in `mycss.css` by overriding them with a second CSS property in the second stylesheet?

I tried the `initial` value for this property, but not working.

Look at my example here:

First property in mycss.css stylesheet:

```css
.myclass { right: 64px; }
```

Second property should be disabled and override by the code below:

```css
.myclass { left: 64px }
```

The problem is that, after writing the second CSS property, both properties remain. I expected the disabling or deleting of the first property with only the second property remaining.

I have a similar problem with `background-color`, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For disabling you can use 'unset'.
For example `background-color: unset;`

Answer (score 0):

All css properties have a default value. You can reset the value to this default to make it ignored.

In the case 'right', the default is 'auto' - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/right)

```
.myclass {right: auto; left: 64px; }
```